# Run Badlion Client in a non-admin account

Tags: windows-10, administrator, minecraft, microsoft-family-safety

My son uses his computer, running Windows 10 Pro, through an account controlled by [Microsoft Family Safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_family_features). He doesn't have administration rights and cannot install software.

I have installed some games for him, among them Minecraft. Because he likes the additional features, my son often plays Minecraft through the [Badlion Client](https://client.badlion.net/). Unlike the other installed apps, which my son can start and use without limitation, every time he starts the Badlion Client Windows asks for an administrator password. This means that my son can only use that software, when I'm in the house, because of course he doesn't know my admin credentials.

That is not what I wanted. I want my son to be able to use the Badlion Client without having to ask me to allow that software first.

**What do I need to do to allow the use of the Badlion Client from an account without administrator rights?**

Please explain giving very simple, step by step instructions. I'm completely unfamiliar with Windows and find the settings overwhelming and confusing.

Comment: [According to the Badlion forums what you want isn’t possible due to how the client works.](https://www.badlion.net/forum/thread/230594#:~:text=Badlion%20Client%20needs%20to%20be%20run%20as%20an,administrative%20password%20each%20time%20you%20open%20Badlion%20Client.)

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At the time you can only Open the Badlion Client WITH Admin perms. The Client Scans your PC to search Cheats, wich will Thema don't Work anymore. That's the only reason for the Client to need Admin perms. Official BLC-website: https://www.badlion.net/forum/thread/231677

Badlion Client
Team

Comment: It would be great, if you could provide some details on that:
_Badlion Client needs to be run as an administrator in order for it to perform some of its core tasks._

What does that mean technically? There are lots of User Rights Assignment policies. Which permissions does the client really need?